# Is there an AWS command or billing API to get the credit details?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I am currently using the following command to get the blended and unblended cost:

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2019-12-01,End=2020-01-01 --granularity MONTHLY --metrics "BlendedCost" "UnblendedCost" "UsageQuantity" --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE
```

Is there any command or an option that I can use to get the credits and its usage? I couldn't find much on AWS's documentation, so posting a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this filter can help...

`aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2020-07-01,End=2020-08-01 --granularity MONTHLY --metrics "BlendedCost" "UnblendedCost" "UsageQuantity" --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE Type=TAG,Key=Environment --filter file://filters.json`

With Filter file
`{ "Dimensions": { "Key": "RECORD_TYPE", "Values": [ "Credit" ] } }`

Without `--group-by` Parameter to get the overall sum of spent credits so far